# Having an issue displaying embed correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hi I'm having an issue displaying an embed correctly. The function is when the command `List` is invoked the bot will send a list of roles in categories. However, when the command is invoked this is what I get

[image]

This isn't the result I was hoping for, it seems the `colours:` is missing here I will show how I'm attempting this in my code.

```
 @commands.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True, name='list', aliases=['roles', 'role'])
async def _list(self, ctx):
    """List of all available roles """
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    author = ctx.message.author
    botroom = self.bot.get_channel(555844758778544160) 
    intros = self.bot.get_channel(485381365366390796)
    colours = ['Blue', 'Yellow', 'Pink', 'Black']
    Games = ['LoL', 'WoW']

    if ctx.message.channel == intros:
        pass
    else:
        if ctx.message.channel == botroom:
            message = '\n**Colours:**\n' # Colour roles category here
            for role in colours: # if roles are colours list this under this category.
                message += '\n{} **({})**'.format(role, len([member for member in guild.members if ([r for r in member.roles if r.name == role])]))
                message += ''
            for role in Games: #if roles are games list this under this category.
                message = '\n**Games:**\n' # Games roles category here
                message += '\n{} **({})**'.format(role, len([member for member in guild.members if ([r for r in member.roles if r.name == role])]))
                message += ''
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Roles List", description=message.format(), colour=0x0080c0)
                embed.set_footer(text="Tip: to add a role from the list type the command !add/remove followed by the role.")
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            await ctx.send('You can only use this command in {}.'.format(botroom.mention))
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong, whether I'm using the formatting incorrectly. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Make change `message = '\n**Games:**\n'` to  `+=` and move it to before the second loop

Comment: Hi I just to want to extend on this question to make the list casesensitive would I need to put something like `if Colours.lower() in roles:` above `for roles in Colours;` or is there a specific way to make lists case sensitive?